# Need to detect mobile browser and load mobile.css file for Joomla template with PHP

Tags: php, css, mobile, joomla, detection

I need to detect if somebody is using a mobile browser (media queries aren't enough in this situation) via php and then load a mobile.css file to override a few lines of css due to lack of proper support for some code I'm using. I'm building a joomla template, so I need it to dynamically generate the path to the css file. So, am I doing this right? Example:

```
<?php
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true) 
{ 
echo "<link rel="stylesheet" href="$this->baseurl/templates/$this->template/css/mobile.css" type="text/css">";
}
?>
```

Comment: I definitely appreciate suggestions for better alternatives to this method and all of those who suggested them (I have been looking into them).. However I still would like to know if my code is valid.. will what I have work? specifically did I do the if statement correctly with the echo and the dynamic path to the css file? Thanks for the help guys. :)

Comment: see my updated answer on the problems I see with your existing code

Answer (score 9):

In Joomla there's mobile detection built in.

If you are using Joomla 3.0, you may use:

```
<?php
$templateUrl = $this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template;
$doc         = JFactory::getDocument();
$appWeb      = new JApplicationWeb; // new JWebClient; (in Joomla 2.5)

if ($appWeb->client->mobile)
{
    $doc->addStyleSheet($templateUrl . '/css/mobile.css');
}
?>
```

in Joomla 2.5 or lower you'd use `$appWeb = new JWebClient`

in Joomla 3.4 you'll probably use `if (JFactory::getApplication()->client->mobile)`

I didn't find documentation page, but you may always inspect [source code](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/application/web/client.php)

*By the way, check out responsive frameworks. It takes time to learn but it's worth to.*

Comment: I already use responsive code I make myself. That isn't the issue. I had a special reason for hiding objects that a javascript that was animating an element based on scroll position... it doesn't work properly on touch screen devices because it doesn't register the scroll until after the scroll is complete. I figured I'd just have the object hidden if it detected a mobile device.

Comment: I'd like to use Joomla 3.0... but I'm not sure if all the extensions I'll be using will be compatible for sure. I have to test that still. But if not 3, then I'll be using Joomla 2.5. So with 2.5 I'd replace the line "if ($appWeb->client->mobile)" with "if ($appWeb = new JWebClient)"? Forgive me I'm very mucha  newbie with php and javascript.

Answer (score 2):

There are libraries available like Mobile_Detect you can use them to detect which channel you are using either desktop, mobile or tablet and can load css accordingly. You can find the download link [here](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/)

Follow this steps:

1 Download the Mobile_detect file from the above link.

2 Put the file in some folder of your project

3 Now include that file in the page where you want to check if the channel is mobile or desktop. i.e
       include mobile_detect.php (something like this)
4) Then once you include the above file do this

```
$this->detect = new Mobile_Detect;
$channel = 'desktop';

if ($this->detect->isTablet() || 't' == $_REQUEST['device']) {
    $channel = 'tablet';
} elseif ($this->detect->isMobile() || 'm' == $_REQUEST['device']) {
     $channel = 'mobile';
}
```

So your $channel variable will have the channel, with this variable you can check if $channel is not equal to desktop then it will be mobile. And you can load mobile.css accordingly. Hope it helps.

Comment: I took a look at that and I'm not sure I could figure out how to properly use the resource... I'm very new to dealing with PHP.. mostly from just hacking PHP code for Joomla (in situations I can figure out what I actually need to do). Are there any simple instructions how to incorporate this with limited understanding?

Comment: Please Mark answer solved if you find it appropriate so that future user can refer to the solution. Thanks

Comment: Yes I was researching between your solution and the built in joomla solution... to determine which solution worked best. I will mark the answer when I come that conclusion. Just a side note, since it's not an obsolete question if I use one of the two methods.. was my code correct in my sample? this part specifically: "echo "<link rel="stylesheet" href="$this->baseurl/templates/$this->template/css/mobile.css" type="text/css">";" I wasn't sure if I was doing it right because normally I just have php echo the dynamic parts of the path but you can't echo inside of an echo....

Comment: I seriously doubt that the echo would work properly; first because the if statements are wrong and also the echo has syntax errors (missing escaping), see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you made clear in your comments that you wish to use your own approach please note that your `if` statement and the `echo` is problematic: 
As [stated in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), `strpos` returns an integer or FALSE so your soft boolean comparison with `==` would not work since a result of integer 0 is a positive match but gets implicitily converted to FALSE. 
Also your `echo` is not escaped; I'd encourage you to use single quotation marks to reduce the risk of missing escaping. An updated code addressing those issues would be like:

```
// ... $iphone = strpos(... etc

if($iphone !== false || $android !== false || $palmpre !== false || $ipod !== false || $berry !== false)
{
  echo('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/css/mobile.css" type="text/css">');
}
```